# vb6 Declare an Array

Tags: arrays, vb6

I have this code :

```
' Option Explicit
Public Function Clean(Text)
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Dim Chars As ?????????
    Chars = Array("\", "/", ":", "*", "?", """", "<", ">", "|")
    For Each Replaced In Chars
        Text = Replace(Text, Replaced, "")
    Next
    Clean = CStr(Text)
End Function
```

But i got an error when use `Option Explicit` because the Chars is not declared, but what type must i use to dim an array (`Dim Chars As ???????`)?

Comment: @george : Thanks for edit, it looks better now...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Corrected version:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Clean(ByVal Text As String)
    Dim Chars As Variant
    Dim Replaced As Variant

    Chars = Array("\", "/", ":", "*", "?", """", "<", ">", "|")
    For Each Replaced In Chars
        Text = Replace(Text, Replaced, "")
    Next
    Clean = Text
End Function
```

Generally better performing version:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Clean(ByVal Text As String)
    Dim Chars As Variant
    Dim RepIndex As Long

    Chars = Array("\", "/", ":", "*", "?", """", "<", ">", "|")
    For RepIndex = 0 To UBound(Chars)
        Text = Replace$(Text, Chars(RepIndex), "")
    Next
    Clean = Text
End Function
```

Understanding Variants is important, and one should be especially conscious of using the Variant version of string functions instead of the String-typed versions suffixed with the "$" type decoration.

Most of the time you'll want to avoid Variants when you can because of performance costs.

This version probably performs even better:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Clean(ByVal Text As String)
    Const Chars As String = "\/:*?""<>|"
    Dim RepIndex As Long

    For RepIndex = 1 To Len(Chars)
        Text = Replace$(Text, Mid$(Chars, RepIndex, 1), "")
    Next
    Clean = Text
End Function
```

There is no "Char" type in VB6, nor is there any initialization syntax on variable declaration.

Comment: For curiosity sake, I ran the different versions plus one more I wrote using regular expressions. I tested it using this test string: "nc834u\7238/4037*?".
The first version took 30 seconds to run 100,000 times.
The second & third versions each took 23 seconds to run 1,000,000 times.
And the regular expression took 17 seconds to 1,000,000 times. A modest increase. 
I should note that the increase was only apparent when compiled and run as an exe. When running in interpreted mode, it ran the same time as versions 2 & 3. I'll post my code in a separate comment in case anyone wants it.

Comment: `Function Clean1(S As String) As String
   Dim regex As New RegExp
   regex.Pattern = "[\\/:\?\*\""\<\>\|]"
   regex.IgnoreCase = True
   regex.Global = True
   Clean1 = regex.Replace(S, "")
End Function`  

Note: You'll have to add the reference to **Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions** for this to work.

Comment: @TimCollins: Try caching the instance creation (`Static`?) -- it will get order of magnitude faster.

Comment: If speed is truly important there are other optimizations that can be done such as not using `Replace$()`, converting to ANSI when applicable and chewing that over, etc. The point of my suggestions was that just by avoiding known problem areas you get benefits with little or no cost.

Answer (score 2):

you can dim it as an array of strings
you won't need a variant to do so

```
Dim Chars() As String
Chars = Split("\,/,:,*,?,"",<,>,|", ",")
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are declared in the same manner as other variables (i.e. using the keywords "Dim", "Private", "Public", etc.), except that the array bounds are coded in parentheses following the variable name (if a fixed-length array is being declared) or an empty pair of parentheses follow the variable name (if a variable-length, or dynamic array is being declared).

```
 Dim Chars As Variant
 Chars = Array("\", "/", ":", "*", "?", """", "<", ">", "|")
```

http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/understanding-arrays

Comment: Your code actually **doesn't works**, but thanks for your link, now i declare it `as Variant`

Comment: Rather than saying it doesn't work can you provide an error message?

Comment: It's error when i type it, because my vb6 can't have an *equal* after DIM `Dim Whatever As Whatever = Whatever`, so the error is not show anything, it just highlight the `=` symbol...

Comment: How can this be an accepted answer?  The provided answer isn't legal VB6 at all.